# calling dbstep from a function

Tags: matlab, debugging

I am trying to write my version of Matlab's debug step command `dbstep`, that is I want to do dbstep and some other things, in a single call. However, putting `dbstep` into a function does not work:

```
% in file my_dbstep.m
function my_dbstep()
evalin('caller', 'dbstep');
```

When I call `my_dbstep` while in a debug session, it acts as if I typed `dbstep` inside the function, and not in the caller.

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to use a mex file, from which I can call a function in Matlab to do stuff I want each time I step a line in debug mode (using this new `dbstep2` mex file), followed by a call to `dbstep` from the mex:

```
// file dbstep2.c
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {    
    mexCallMATLAB(0,NULL,0, NULL, "do_some_stuff");
    mexCallMATLAB(0,NULL,0, NULL, "dbstep");
}
```

In my case, I use the `do_some_stuff` function to send key strokes to vim while debugging in Matlab (no gui), so the current line is highlighted in the script which is opened in vim. Of course it can be used to any other use case.